# Is there a way to send an email to Teams members when a file is added to the team or channel?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I know that a team member can "Start a Conversation" on a newly added file, but in case the team member does not do this, I'm looking for a way to automatically notify all team members about the new file. Is there a bot that can do this? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files for a Team are driveItems in the [the document library associated with the group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-the-document-library-associated-with-a-group). You can [subscribe to changes to the library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and update users as appropriate.